# Spring 4 jackson Restful POST rest client call fails 405

Tags: spring, rest, post, junit

I have wrote a GET and a POST end point. Thought Advanced REST client I can do a successful GET call. But the POST end point fails from REST client. It gives 405 Method Not Allowed Status. What is the issues here?

Dependencies

```
<!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/orders")
public class OrderRestController {

@Autowired
private FoodItemService foodItemService;

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public OrderDto addOrder(OrderDto orderDto){
    return orderDto;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public OrderDto getOrder(){
    FoodItem foodItem = foodItemService.findOne(1, Boolean.TRUE);
    OrderDto orderDto = new OrderDto();
    orderDto.setRoomId(23);
    Map<FoodItem, Integer> orders = new HashMap<FoodItem, Integer>();
    orders.put(foodItem, 3);
    return orderDto;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I made a try with your code and it works for me. I don't know exactly which Spring configuration and format (JSON) you use for your RESTful service with Spring4.

Here is the maven configuration I used:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my configuration in the file `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the configuration I use in the file `springmvc-servlet.xml` to configure the bean / content conversion:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <!-- JSON View -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I can execute a request like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/restapp/rest/orders
{
    "orderDto": {
        "id": "some id",
        "name": "some name",
        "roomId": 23
    }
}

200 OK
```

For the class `OrderDto`, I used fake structure and data ;-)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I'm using spring 4 so I didn't create the bean. Thought spring would create itself.

Any chance of pushing the code to git hub, So I can have a look. Thanks for the reply Thierry.

Comment: Yes sure! You can reach it here: https://github.com/templth/restlet-stackoverflow/tree/master/spring/test-spring-mvc-jackson. Tell me if it helps you ;-)

Comment: Thanks Thierry. Apparently it was my security filter causing trouble. Once I comment security filter from web.xml everything works(well except login stuff). I add an entry to security filter to permit all.
<intercept-url pattern="/rest**" access="permitAll" />
But didn't help.

Comment: Actually I didn't find the solution yet. I found the issue. Still in the hunt for the solution.

Comment: Could you update your question to add the configuration of the filter? So I can make a test... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue wasn't of jackson. Issue was csrf being enabled. Should do a further research of disabling csrf and security but for the moment disabling it is the solution.